# How to filter flowfiles based on the data in it?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

One output flowfile has 23 rows of data, each row in the flowfile has a key and value. There are a lot of similar flowfiles in the queue, if any of those flowfiles does not have all the required rows of data they need to go to unmatched queue. Which processor or method of approach should I use to implement this scenario, or can I do this filteration in jolt?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use a processor like `ExecuteGroovyScript` (https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-groovyx-nar/1.25.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript/index.html). In it, you have access to the flow file to check all the rows and then route to a different relationship (success / failure) depending on the result of the check.